# jquery to loop through each table row and perform math with each row input field

Tags: jquery

I have the below table

```
<table class="authors-list" border=0 id="ordertable">
    <tr>
        <td>Cubic Meters</td><td>Cubes per Bundle</td><td>Total Bundles</td>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters1" id="cubicmeters1" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle1" id="cubesperbundle1" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles1" id="bundles1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters2" id="cubicmeters2" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle2" id="cubesperbundle2" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles2" id="bundles2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubicmeters3" id="cubicmeters3" value="1.38"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="cubesperbundle3" id="cubesperbundle3" value="1.485"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="bundles3" id="bundles3"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

what I want to do is loop through each table row and perform a math function against two inputs, and populate the result into a third input.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ttZtX/1/

So here is my attempt at the jquery:

```
$("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicmeters1"]').each(function () {
    cubes += +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val();
    cubesperbundle += +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
    +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

This simply produces no result or error and the input is not populated.

To summarize, my requirement is for jquery to loop through each row, multiply `cubicmeters` by `cubesperbundle` and populate `bundles` with the result.

simple enough but I just cant get it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selected `No wrap - in <head>` in your fiddle so the elements that you are trying to select has not yet been created, try changing it to `onDomready`
Also remove the `1` in `$("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicmeters1"]')` to select all the input instead of just one and add `var` before your variables so they don't leak into the global scope

```
$("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').each(function () {
    var cubes = +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val();
    var cubesperbundle = +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttZtX/19/

Comment: Thanks Musa. can this work if in the body itself. trouble is the cubicmeters and cubesperbundle are populated by an earlier jquery function and this is run in the body so I need to trigger this script from the body, after the inputs have been populated. Thanks

Comment: @Smudger it doesn't matter where the code is, it matters when it is called. You need to call it after the dom has loaded(or just when the elements it operate on are loaded)

Comment: Thanks. this is currently after all the other scripts in body. How do I achieve this? the other inputs are populated by this script: `for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    (function (index) {
        $.post('get_sku_pieces', {
            data: $('#product' + index).val()
        }, function (result) {
            $('#pcsperbundle' + index).val(result);
        });
    })(i)
}`

Comment: @Smudger try [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code here*/});`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/WrvmW/

```
$("table.authors-list tr").each(function () {
   var cubes = parseFloat($('input[name^="cubicmeters"]',this).val(), 10);
    var cubesperbundle = parseFloat($('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]',this).val(), 10);
    $('input[name^="bundles"]',this).val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2))

});
```

There were some error in your `javascript` and you need to `parseFloat` it for performing operations. Another thing is you dont have to complicate it by `each` ing on the input and finding the `closest`. You can directly loop through `tr`s.

Comment: Hi, it didn't and probably my fault as I failed to mention that this script will be called from within the body. can this work if in the body itself. trouble is the cubicmeters and cubesperbundle are populated by an earlier jquery function and this is run in the body so I need to trigger this script from the body, after the inputs have been populated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have got error in your javascript:

```
$("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicmeters1"]').each(function () {
    // you haven't declared cubes
    // you have a + in front of $
    // you're not parsing the string (use parseFloat)
    cubes += +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val();
    cubesperbundle += +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val();
    +$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

The following should work:

```
$(function(){       
        $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="cubicmeters1"]').each(function () {
            var cubes;
            var cubesperbundle;
            cubes = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubicmeters"]').val());
            cubesperbundle = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="cubesperbundle"]').val());
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="bundles"]').val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
        });
});
```

Comment: OP is using `+ in front of $` to convert the string returned from `val` to a number.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. Can this work if in the body itself. trouble is the cubicmeters and cubesperbundle are populated by an earlier jquery function and this is run in the body so I need to trigger this script from the body, after the inputs have been populated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you change your table structure for some reason like more complex calculations there is always another way like addressing the issue with id selectors. You can see it at :

http://jsfiddle.net/ttZtX/24/

or here

```
$('input[name^="bundles"]').each(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("bundles", "");

  var cubes = +$("#cubicmeters" + id).val();

  var cubesperbundle = +$("#cubesperbundle" + id).val();

  $(this).val((cubes*cubesperbundle).toFixed(2));
});
```

where each bundle is already carrying its id number so you can find related number of items and add them to your calculation logic.

Comment: Thanks kubarium. can this work if in the body itself. trouble is the cubicmeters and cubesperbundle are populated by an earlier jquery function and this is run in the body so I need to trigger this script from the body, after the inputs have been populated. Thanks

Comment: This technique can work anywhere on the page since you are selecting with IDs but not in nested places. To answer your other question, let's say you have a button that will trigger this calculation, put all this code in the click event handler of that button. So, when it's clicked it'll try to find bundles, cubicmeters and etc even though they have been put in the DOM after page load. What you ultimately need sounds like a different question so you may want to open a new thread instead so other can easily find it. It'd get lost here in the comments area.